# How to join subplot windows?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Suppose a 3x2 subplot grid; on the upper 2x2 I seek to make four different plots, but the bottom 1x2 is to be a "joint" window like below. Two ideas: (1) plot as a single figure to enable `fig.savefig()`; (2) preserve width and height, i.e. the "joint" plot should span two subplot windows (not necessarily 2x the width of either), and be of same height. MATLAB is able to do this, unsure of matplotlib.

---

**Goal image**:

[image]

---

**Image code**:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randn(6, 100, 100)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True, dpi=72)  # 2x2 for demo

for x, ax in zip(X[:4], axes.flat[:4]):
    ax.imshow(x)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=.6, bottom=0, top=1, wspace=.01, hspace=.01)
plt.show()

plt.imshow(X[-2:].reshape(100, 200))
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(9.15, 5.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: There is [an example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_and_subplots.html) in matplotlib's official documentation. It uses `gridspec` to set the ratio's between the subplots. There also is a more [involved example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html).

Comment: @JohanC Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a [docs example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_and_subplots.html) (thanks @JohanC), this can be accomplished by replacing axes of interest with a "joint axis" specified by a [`GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randn(6, 100, 100)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(9, 9))

for x, ax in zip(X, axes.flat[:-2]):
    ax.imshow(x)

gs = axes[0, 0].get_gridspec()
for ax in axes[-1, :]:
    ax.remove()
axbig = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1, :])
axbig.imshow(X[-2:].reshape(100, 200))

fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1, wspace=-.5, hspace=.02)
```

[image]